# ¿Cómo obtener el Value de un botón con JavaScript y pasarlo a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Mi conocimiento de `JS` es muy muy básico por eso es que estoy realizando esta consulta, tengo el siguiente bloque de código en `PHP` en el cual imprimo varios datos que vienen desde la base de datos.

```
    echo "<tr>";
 echo '<td>'.$titulo['post_title'].'</td>';
 print_r('<td>'.$estado['meta_value'].', '.$ciudad['meta_value'].', '.$direccion['meta_value'].'</td>');
 print_r('<td>'.$metros['meta_value'].' mts2</td>');
 print_r('<td>'.$precio['meta_value'].' ARS</td>');
 echo "<td><button type='button' value='$idPub2' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm' onclick='fnPublicar()'><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span></button></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Ahora lo que necesito es tomar el `value` y la información de cada fila y pasarlo a un `json`. Actualmente me toma el valor del último `value` que se imprime (por los momentos tengo 3 registros en BD), este el `JS` que tengo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fnPublicar(){
    var idFnPublicar = '<?php echo $idPub2; ?>';
      console.log(idFnPublicar);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: falta ver la parte del código js para ver que llevas realizado hasta el momento, en tu pregunta hablas sobre el `id` del botón pero no veo que lo estés usando.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura del JSON que quieres obtener? ¿En qué evento quieres obtener? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: @Andrés ya edité lo que tengo de JS, Quizás es que estoy formulando mal la pregunta.  Es el value que necesito no el ID, disculpen.

Comment: @Davlio quiero que cuando presiones click sobre el botón, este obtenga todos los datos que imprimo en la fila y genere un JSON que posteriormente utilizaré utilizando curl en php.

Answer (score 1):

feliz año!, te voy a dejar un ejemplo de como lograr esto utilizando la librería [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), te recomiendo utilizarla es fácil de aprender.

Suponiendo que tu tabla tiene un id = "tabla" puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Recorre las filas de la tabla
$('#tabla tr').each(function () {
   //Recorre las columnas de las filas
   $(this).children("td").each(function (index) {     
     //Pregunto que fila es y voy guardando los valores a diferentes variables
     switch (index) {       
      case 1:
       var columna1 = $(this).text();
      break;
      case 2:
       var columna2 = $(this).text();
       break;
      case 3:
       var columna3 = $(this).text();
       break;
     }
   }
}
```

Para obtener el valor del botón te recomiendo agregarle un id como te pongo aquí:

Obtienes el valor de la siguiente forma:

```
var valorBoton = $('#boton-ejemplo').val();
```

Saludos y espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Por medio de **javaScript** puro puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function fnPublicar(e) {
  var linea = e.parentElement.parentElement;
  var hijos = linea.getElementsByTagName("td");

  var datos = JSON.parse('{"titulo": "' + hijos[0].innerHTML + '" , "direccion": "' + hijos[1].innerHTML + '",    "metros": "' + hijos[2].innerHTML + '",    "coste": "' + hijos[3].innerHTML + '" }');

  console.log(datos);

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>El asilo del abuelo</td>
    <td>California, Venta</td>
    <td>300 mts2</td>
    <td>150000 EUR</td>
    <td><button type='button' value='$idPub2' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm' onclick='fnPublicar(this)'><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span> click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>El llano</td>
    <td>Tenerife, alquiler</td>
    <td>1500 mts2</td>
    <td>300 ARS</td>
    <td><button type='button' value='$idPub2' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm' onclick='fnPublicar(this)'><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span> click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vivienda familiar</td>
    <td>Madrid, Venta</td>
    <td>150 mts2</td>
    <td>50000 ARS</td>
    <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm' onclick='fnPublicar(this)'><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span> click me</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Por otro lado y pensando de la misma forma que **Lucas Accastello** el uso de **jquery** simplifica mucho el manejo de los *elementos DOMs*.

Aquí un ejempo:

```js
$('.btn-outline-info').on('click', function (){
var datos;
var titulo, direccion, metros, coste;
 $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(index){
     switch (index) {       
          case 0:
            titulo = $(this).text();
          break;
          case 1:
            direccion = $(this).text();
           break;
          case 2:
            metros = $(this).text();
           break;
          case 3:
            coste = $(this).text();
         }
     
  });
  var datos = JSON.parse('{"titulo": "' + titulo + '" , "direccion": "' + direccion + '",    "metros": "' + metros + '",    "coste": "' + coste + '" }');

 console.log(datos)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>El asilo del abuelo</td>
    <td>California, Venta</td>
    <td>300 mts2</td>
    <td>150000 EUR</td>
    <td><button type='button' value='$idPub2' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm'><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span> click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>El llano</td>
    <td>Tenerife, alquiler</td>
    <td>1500 mts2</td>
    <td>300 ARS</td>
    <td><button type='button' value='$idPub2' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm'><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span> click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vivienda familiar</td>
    <td>Madrid, Venta</td>
    <td>150 mts2</td>
    <td>50000 ARS</td>
    <td><button type='button' value='$idPub2' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm' ><span class='oi oi-check' title='Publicar'></span> click me</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```